# How to call a method variable in another method?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

I need to find out how to get the return of the `computerChoice` method into the `playGame` method to print out the computer's random choice.

The last method isn't complete after that print statement; I am just stuck on this part.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
    private InputReader reader;
    private int yourScore;
    private int computerScore;
    private Random ran;

   
    public RockPaperScissors()
    {
        reader = new InputReader();
        yourScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
        ran = new Random(1);
    }


    public void printPrompt()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter your choice, paper, rock or scissors >");
       
    }
    
    public String userChoice()
    {
        String input = reader.getInput();
        input = input.trim().toLowerCase();
        return input;
    }
    
    public String computerChoice()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int myRanInt = ran.nextInt(3);
        String computerRanChoice ="";
        switch(myRanInt) {
        case 0: computerRanChoice = "paper";
                break;
        case 1: computerRanChoice = "scissors";
                break;
        case 2: computerRanChoice = "rock";
                break;
    }
        return computerRanChoice;
    }
    
    public void playGame()
    
    {
        System.out.println("The computers choice is " + computerRanChoice);
        
    }
```

Comment: We can call the method `computerChoice()` from within method `playGame()`: `final String computerChoice = computerChoice();`.

Comment: Add parenthesis: `System.out.println("The computers choice is " + computerRanChoice());`

Comment: What your trying to do is not "to call method variable from another method" (wich is not possible), but just catching the value returned by this method. `String myValueReturned = computerRanChoice();` and then display this value in your log : `System.out.println("Choice is " + myValueReturned);`

Comment: `public void playGame() { System.out.println("The computers choice is: -->  " + computerChoice()); }`.

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is to call the member function `computerChoice()` inside the function `playGame()`. There is an example below.

It seems that you are missing a game loop. It is an [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) that keeps you game running until an event appers.

Your `playGame()` function should implement that loop, to take turns. Something like

```
    public void playGame()
    {
        while (1) 
        {
            printPrompt();
            String userMove = this.userChoice();
            String computerRanChoice = this.computerChoice();
            // Compare and set the winner
            System.out.println("The computers choice is " + computerRanChoice);
        }
 
    }
```

The Input read will lock the execution until something is read.

I suggest to add a user input that breaks the loop and finish the game.